# Doctrine2 - relation depending on parameter

Tags: php, mysql, entity-framework, doctrine-orm

I would like to know what is the best way to have an entity with 1:N relation to another entity but additionally depending on a parameter.

For example I have `product`entity and `product_description` entity, which depends on `product_id` and also on `language` (2 char code). Another examples would be `manufacturer` and `manufacturer_description`, `category` and `category_description`. There is a lot of it - you got the idea.

I though about extending `EntityRepository` class and adding automatic join based for example on an annotation. I'm just not sure if this is the "correct way" to do what I want. Can you suggest better solution? Another though was just to have method `getDescription($language)` in `product` entity but to me it just doesn't look as best solution, especially because I want to load the language-dependent content in 90% cases with all other information. Getting that content in separate query would just create unnecessary load.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a translatable extensions for doctrine. I've never used it but it looks like it might address your use case:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/2010/11/18/doctrine2-behavioral-extensions.html

See also

https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions

Comment: I've just checked it and it looks too complicated. I mean the way how to obtain entities, insert new ones and so is just strange. Especially the way how it stores data in database. I will look at the details but I think that I won't stick with that. Thank you for suggestion anyway :)

Comment: You could also consider adding a doctrine filter to add an extra clause to query for languae http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html :-)

Comment: That looks much better - thank you, I will take a look into it :-)

Comment: What do you think about https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors? To me it looks like Gedmo but much simplier while it achieve the same functionality (and according to code it's "by default" more efficient [creates another table for translations]). I just never heard about it before.

Comment: Looks good to me! KNP Labs are well known too, I'd say give it a try :-)